# Название кнопки

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка, у кнопки есть `id`, это кнопка присуствует на каждой странице, но на разных страницах, у нее разные `id`. К примеру, на первой странице у нее `id` `buttonsd123` на другой `buttonsd213`. Как сделать правильный `var`, чтобы он брал по `buttonsd` а что уже дальше не важно.

Примерно так:

```
var knopka = document.getElementById('buttonsd//и тут уже любые значения')
```

Страниц более 1000, ведь в каждую не писать id кнопки..

Comment: А jQuery есть на странице?

Comment: Привет, jQuery  нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/attr3
Пример по ссылке: http://codepen.io/Besmer/pen/qOqqzE
Просто реализация:

```
document.querySelector('button[id^=buttonsd]')
```

Comment: Можешь, пожалуйста, подробнее описать т.к. не работает... Но спасибо!

Comment: Странно, должно работать. Проверьте поддержку querySelector у вашего браузера, но она должна быть у всех браузеров на текущий момент.
Если не работает, то подключить jquery/аналоги или воспользоваться менее оптимизированным, но работающим следующим ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Если без jQuery то так:

```
var elems = [];
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if(buttons[i].id.indexOf('buttonsd') == 0) {
        elems.push(buttons[i]);
    }
}
```

В elems будут находится обьекты кнопок на странице. Тоесть если на каждой странице по одной кнопке, то в elems находится та самая кнопка.